# Crash Reporting showing Null Pointer and Array out of bounds Exception when sending the data to server

Tags: codenameone

My app is running with issues but due to pro subscription, I do see these logs come to the email registered. I do not see this issue when I test connecting with USB to Android Studio. I know this is a null pointer due to the operation on a null and array out-of-bounds object. How would I know where in the code this is being caused? I see with the request that send the info to the server. This huge request so the error does not say which argument or line that is throwing a null pointer here. Any thoughts on the approach to be taken?

``
Codename One revisions: 7dd4e7d08b3442d90959477ee52a5ae8c4361b29
[EDT] 1:36:42,493 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com_codename1_ui_Form.pointerReleased:3835
at com_codename1_ui_Component.pointerReleased:4729
at com_codename1_ui_Display.handleEvent:2324
at com_codename1_ui_Display.edtLoopImpl:1216
at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:1134
at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.run:120
at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176
at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153

```
[Network Thread] 10:4:43,330 - The network connection was lost.
                [Network Thread] 10:4:43,336 - Exception: java.io.IOException - The network connection was lost.
               java.io.IOException
    at com_codename1_io_ConnectionRequest.performOperationComplete:964
    at com_codename1_io_NetworkManager_NetworkThread.run:340
    at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176
    at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153
                [EDT] 10:4:43,403 - Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException - 0 out of: 0
               java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com_codename1_ui_Form.pointerReleased:3835
    at com_codename1_ui_Component.pointerReleased:4729
    at com_codename1_ui_Display.handleEvent:2324
    at com_codename1_ui_Display.edtLoopImpl:1216
    at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:1134
    at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.run:120
    at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176
    at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153
        [EDT] 10:4:43,405 - Exception in version 
    [EDT] 10:4:43,406 - OS ios
     [EDT] 10:4:43,407 - Error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 out of: 0
     [EDT] 10:4:43,407 - Current Form null
```

``

Answer (score 0):

This is from an older version of Codename One since [that specific line](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Form.java#L3835C9-L3835C9) can't be null in any circumstance. Since the file was last changed 2 years ago I'm guessing this is from a very old version.

Network connection lost is something normal that can get reported by the default crash protection code. It might be valid as cell service sometimes fails.

If these emails are a problem you can filter them based on the app version in the title since there's probably no need to review crashes from older versions.